# When do you use Addition Rule or Product Rule?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm a little confused on whether I should use the Addition Rule or Product Rule...

There are 20 male and 15 female students in a class. In how many ways can you choose a committee of 5 students if it should have 3 male students and 2 female students?

My Work:

$$
{20\choose 3}+{15\choose 2} = 1245
$$

OR

$$
{20\choose 3}*{15\choose 2} = 119700
$$

Looking at the numbers, I'm leaning towards the Addition Rule. I just want to know if I am right and why!

Thanks!

Comment: The product rule comes in because for each choice of the male students you need to choose a set of female students.  If you have $m$ choices of male students and $n$ choices of female students, you have $mn$ choices overall.  This works when the second choice does not depend on which of the first choices you made.  You have split the big problem into two smaller problems, which often are easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to rephrase combinatorical questions purely in terms of sets. Let $B$ be the set of all boys and $G$ be the set of all girls. We know that $|B|=20$ and $|G|=15$. We are interested in the size of the set $S$, which consists of 5-elements subsets of $B\cup G$, with the property that three of its elements are from $B$ and two of its elements are from $G$. Any such 5-subset can be re-arranged into the form (since order does not matter) $\{ b_1,b_2,b_3,g_1,g_2\}$. Now it is clear that $|S| = |B_3|\times |G_2|$ where $B_3$ are the number of three-elements subsets of $B$, and similarly for $G_2$.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, ${20\choose 3}*{15\choose 2} = 119700$ is the correct answer?

Comment: Dear mr Philip:

Yes!

Comment: Awesome, the way you explained it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You should use product rule because both cases are dependent. Addition rule is used when you have several cases that are independent one of another. In this case the right answer should be the product rule because you need to pick both male and female students at the same time, that means those picks are dependent one of another.

Comment: So the second part of my answer is correct?

Comment: @PhilipHardy Yes, sometimes combinatorics seem weird based on how big numbers can get with such ease, but it's true.

Comment: Your phrasing is incorrect.  The Multiplication Rule states that if one event can be performed in $m$ ways, and a second event can be performed independently of the first in $n$ ways, then there are $mn$ ways that both events can occur.   The Addition Rule states that if one event can occur in $m$ ways and a second event that cannot occur at the same time can occur in $n$ ways, then the number of possible ways both events can occur is $m + n$.